# boost::asio send get request after ssl connection

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, boost-asio, get-request

I'm using boost::asio and I've been looking at the [example code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp) on how to connect to an ssl host. But I want to send a get request after I've connected to the server through ssl, how is this possible? Do I send a get request as the http example do exactly?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg make your comment an answer

Answer (score 0):

After the handshake is done (`handle_handshake` in the example) and there was no errors, you should be able to use the connection just as any other Boost ASIO connection.